# Should I handle navigation in my reducer? React Native - Wix Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-navigation

What I am trying to accomplish is when a user clicks on a button, such as "Sign In", I fire my action which sets my state in my app state reducer to `loading:true` and the loading screen pops up. I would like to have that functionality across my screens just by setting my show loading state to true via an action.

I do not know if it would be wrong or not to have the navigator in my reducer and have it fire a navigation even after setting my state. I feel like my reducer should handle my state and nothing else. Should it be in my action file?

At this point of my app, everything works... all the console logins fires at the right time. I am just not sure where I should fire the [show lightbox event](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=showlightboxparams-) in a way that I can use on multiple screens.

#### thank you for looking!

#### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "date-fns": "^1.28.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "native-base": "^2.3.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.4",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.143",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
```

#### actions/appStateActions.js

```
import {
  APP_LOADING_SCREEN,
  APP_LOADING_BUTTON
} from './actionTypes';


export const showLoadingScreen = () => async dispatch => {
  console.log("this is loading screen action");
  dispatch({ type: APP_LOADING_SCREEN, payload: true });

}

export const showLoadingButton = () => async dispatch => {
  console.log("this is loading button action");
  dispatch({ type: APP_LOADING_BUTTON, payload: true });
}
```

#### reducers/appStateReducer

```
import{
  APP_LOADING_SCREEN,
  APP_LOADING_BUTTON
} from '../actions/actionTypes';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isLoadingScreenVisible: false,
  isLoadingButtonVisible: false
};


export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type){
    case APP_LOADING_SCREEN:
      return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE, isLoadingScreenVisible: action.payload };
    case APP_LOADING_BUTTON:
      return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE, isLoadingButtonVisible: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

my login screen is complete, albeit without a loading indicator but I have posted only part of it below

```
 loginSubmit(){
    this.props.showLoadingScreen(); 
  }

<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1.5} onPress={() => this.loginSubmit() }>
   <View style={styles.button}
         <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text> 
   </View>
</TouchableOpacity>

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
  const { locationDisplay, locationValue, serviceUrl } = auth;
  
  return { locationDisplay, locationValue, serviceUrl };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {loginUser, showLoadingScreen})(LoginScreen);
```

Comment: Which screen or screens are visible *is* a part of your app's state.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I use a Redux setup in Swift native code rather than react-native. Part of my state is an array of the current screen stack and I have a component that monitors that part of the state and presents or dismisses screens based on what is in that array. Making a screen appear or disappear is simply a matter of adding/removing an item to/from that array and the component takes care of the rest. I can easily see what screens are currently presented by looking at that array in my state...

Answer (score 0):

My understanding says that your reducer should remain a pure function without issuing any side effects. So, in short, no - you probably should not handle navigation in the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

in react we make use of middle ware like saga. in that we dispatch action when our response get success or fail. if success and if you want to navigate you can use that inside saga base on condition. let say i want to navigate once my response reach, then i can use if statement and navigate screen.